# associations sequelize of NUll

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

i'm need request to database
I'm trying to use associations
But I don't get anything as NULL
My two tables have the field `fdID`, But it's like they don't see it
use migrations

```
User.hasOne(Fdo, {
foreignKey: "fdID",
targetKey: "id",
 as: "fdo",
 });
Fdo.hasOne(User, {
  foreignKey: "fdID",
  targetKey: "id",
  as: "user",
});


        let text = await Fdo.findOne({where: { id: req.body['id'] },
        include: [
          {
            association: "user",
            // required: true,
          },
        ]})
            console.log(text.user);
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: @Anatoly error null, don't record searching

Comment: Please show the generated SQL in the post